# Google analytics - auto report to third party

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

I'm working with google analytics integrated in my website and I wonder if there is any way to send auto reports to third party companies.

For example, I want to send every day/week the number of session and users in my website to other company that can help me with statistics and other improvements.

I know that I can send report in few formats like csv and more, but I wonder if there is any server2server approach or something automatically which will report to 3rd parties about my statistics without any additional work on their side (for example, reading/parsing files)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: With a little bit of work on your part you can always use the [Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) there are also a large number of [third party Application Integrations](https://www.google.com/analytics/partners/search/apps) that might have what you are looking for.

Comment: So if I understand correctly the third party company can also implement a connector for GA and then I just authorize it?

Comment: Yes. All Google's API's use [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2): the end user of the application authorizes the application to access the user's Analytics accounts with a specific [scope](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization#scopes). Once authorized the application can then use the Analytics Reporting API to retrieve the data and integrate that data into any system, like a CRM system.

Comment: Take a look at the [Python service account quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py#3_setup_the_sample) for an example of how you can write a simple server applicaiton to access your data.